# Flutter flutter_libserialport to communicate from PC to Arduino Uno recognizes port is open but only writes 1-2 bytes and stops

Tags: flutter, dart, arduino, serial-port, libserial

I am writing bytes from a flutter application to an Arduino Uno. The Uno has some very simple code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    delay(100);
  }
}
```

I am just checking to see if anything has been written across the Serial port and if it has then it will blink continuously

This is a basic test application I made to test the functionality of flutter_libserialport

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_libserialport/flutter_libserialport.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SerialPortExample(),
    );
  }
}

class SerialPortExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SerialPortExampleState createState() => _SerialPortExampleState();
}

class _SerialPortExampleState extends State<SerialPortExample> {
  final _port = SerialPort('COM5');

  void _sendMessage() async {
    // _port.openReadWrite();
    if (_port.isOpen) {
      final message = Uint8List.fromList([65]); // Sending 'A'
      final result = await _port.write(message);
      print('Wrote $result bytes to serial port');
    } else {
      print('Serial port is not open');
    }
    // _port.close();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _port.openReadWrite();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _port.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Serial Port Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("test"),
              onPressed: () {
                _port.openReadWrite();
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Send Character'),
              onPressed: _sendMessage,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this code, I just have two buttons. One to send an 'A' across the serial and one open the port (I was trying to debug). For some reason, I get this error:

```
flutter: Wrote 1 bytes to serial port
flutter: Wrote 1 bytes to serial port
flutter: Wrote 0 bytes to serial port
flutter: Wrote 0 bytes to serial port
flutter: Wrote 0 bytes to serial port
flutter: Wrote 0 bytes to serial port
...
flutter: Wrote 0 bytes to serial port
```

The LED does not turn on. This error occurs pretty often but sometimes it will work as intended. Sending bytes using putty or the Arduino serial monitor works. I have the Arduino IDE closed when I run the flutter app. What is the cause of this error? How can I fix this? Thanks.